# having multiple buttons in one form and every button should be able to update database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery

Hi Friends please tell me where I am wrong cause the database is still unchanged even though update query is executed successfully
Thank you

here is the form code

```
echo'<form action="processor.php" method="post" id ="post_form">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name= "status" id="status" value="">';
$upload_arr=array("1");
foreach($upload_arr as $upload_id)
{
    echo '<input type="button" name="accept-<?=$upload_id?>"   value="accept"             onclick="submit_this(this.name)"/><br>';
    echo    '<input type="button" name="reject-<?=$upload_id?>"  value="reject"  onclick="submit_this(this.name)"/><br>';
    echo    '<input type="button" name="saccept-<?=$upload_id?>"   value="saccept" onclick="submit_this(this.name)"/><br>';
    echo    '<input type="button" name="sreject-<?=$upload_id?>"   value="sreject"       onclick="submit_this(this.name)"/><br>';
 }
echo '</form>';
```

Note :here i have used $upload_id a php variable which has row[upload id] i.e. it is like accept 1,reject1,saccept1 ans sreject1 for first image and for second image it is accept2 reject2 and so on

Now the code for processor.php

```
$status_pass = isset($_POST['status'])?$_POST['status']:NULL;
if(!empty($status_pass)){
$status_arr = explode('-', $status_pass);
$action  = $status_arr[0];
$upload_id = $status_arr[1];

if($action == 'accept'){
    $status = 1;
}
if($action == 'reject'){
    $status = 2;
}
if($action == 'saccept'){
    $status = 3;
}
if($action == 'sreject'){
    $status = 4;
}
echo $status;
$sql="UPDATE upload SET status='$status' where upload_id = '$upload_id' ";
echo "update success";
 $result = mysql_query("$sql") or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());

}
```

Comment: how to set $upload_id in php code?

Comment: Is it not that you just need to add a where clause? `UPDATE upload SET status=4 WHERE id =... `

Comment: yes sir that is my question what exaclty i have to write in where because where should b equal to the value of button clicked like in accept2 secnd image's status shud change to 1 ..thatsy i want button value from form in processor.php which i am unable to send..please help @Moob

Comment: What do you mean by '*...am unable to send*'? When you click on a submit button what happens? Does the form submit?

Comment: sir i have 4 buttons for one image and i have multiple images fetched now on clicking specific button like image1's acept,reject,saccept,sreject button status should change to 1,2,3,4 respectively but on clickin any button status is not changing @Moob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your form

```
<form action="processor.php" method="post" id ='post_form'>
  <input type="hidden" name= "status" id="status" value="">
  <?php
    foreach($upload_arr as $upload_id){
  ?>
      <input type="button" name="accept-<?=$upload_id?>"   value="accept" onclick='submit_this(this.name);'/><br>
      <input type="button" name="reject-<?=$upload_id?>"  value="reject" onclick='submit_this(this.name);'/><br>
      <input type="button" name="saccept-<?=$upload_id?>"   value="saccept" onclick='submit_this(this.name);'/><br>
      <input type="button" name="sreject-<?=$upload_id?>"   value="sreject" onclick='submit_this(this.name);'/><br>
  <?php
    }
  ?>
</form>
<script>
function submit_this(name){
    document.getElementById('status').value = name;
    document.getElementById('post_form').submit();
}
</script>
```

in you php file

```
<?php
$status_pass = isset($_POST['status'])?$_POST['status']:NULL;

if(!empty($status_pass)){
    $status_arr = explode('-', $status_pass);
    $action  = $status_arr[0];
    $upload_id = $status_arr[1];

    if($action == 'accept'){
        $status = 1;
    }
    if($action == 'reject'){
        $status = 2;
    }
    if($action == 'saccept'){
        $status = 3;
    }
    if($action == 'sreject'){
        $status = 4;
    }

    $sql="UPDATE upload SET status='$status' where upload_id = '$upload_id' ";
    //execute sql here
}


?>
```

Comment: sir thanx for reply but i guess id ="post_form" instead id ='post_form' still facing problm :\

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: $upload_arr is a array puts all your uploaded_id, you must give it a value before used in foreach ...

Comment: now it was executed successfuly but the status dint change its still 0 from where i started ..:(

Comment: and one more thing i would like to inform you while defining array if i create array of 3 upload id like $upload_arr=array("1","2","3"); than for one image 4+4+4=12 buttons are comming so i had to make it one to get only 4 buttons for one image ..

Comment: sir good news ..:) :) now m getting status value on each button click..jus left with update query..

Comment: Sir Status is not changing in database though update query is running successfully

Comment: you can try pinrt_r($_POST) to see what you get form your form, and echo the $sql to see if the query is right, good luck...

Comment: echo "<p>" . print_r($_POST) . "</p>";    $sql="UPDATE upload SET status='$status' where upload_id = '$upload_id' ";
 echo $sql;Output:- Array ( [status] => reject- )
1

UPDATE upload SET status='2' where upload_id = ''        I guess there is some problem with where clause thatsy database is not updated

Answer (score 0):

can you please replace **$_POST["accept'.$upload_id.'"]** this with **$_POST["accept".$upload_id]**

Comment: lemme try btw thnx for such a quick respond ^_^

Comment: echo $_POST["accept".$upload_id]; there is nothing on display :(

Answer (score 0):

Don't use '' quotes for $upload_id input tag, It will work then properly

Comment: hi what i write in my my answer?

Comment: there are no need to copy paste

Comment: you mean in form i have to change :o

Comment: accept-<?=$upload_id?> Dont use <?= ?> into echo statement, you can use simple accept-$upload_id

Answer (score 0):

there's some problems of your code

First

if you want to multiple submit form, the type shuold be button, you can use javascript to contorl submit form, and before submit, you can also pass some value to a hidden input field, as your example, you can set hidden input value =  "accept'.$upload_id.'"

Second

in your php file,

$sql="UPDATE upload SET status='1'";

has no where condition, of course, this will update all your records.

Comment: would you please explain me in detail ..and i knw whole field will update thats where i am stuck what to write in where condition and please gimme details of what u said about javascript..thanks

Comment: I have write down the code, but this is not the only option for doing this.

Comment: sir i tried your code ...but in output no button is displayed error is like Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ..

Comment: $upload_arr is a array puts all your uploaded_id, you must give it a value before used in foreach ...

Comment: okay sir m now tryin by assigning values in $upload_array i hope it works well :)